# React: how print conditionally

Tags: reactjs

I need to return conditionally a `<Row>` or `</Row>` if an index is 3 or multiple.

```js
{
                            companyConfiguration.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    // here
                                    {index%3===0 && <Row>}
                                    <Col>
                                        <FormComponent
                                            key={index}
                                            field={item}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            currentItem={{}}
                                        />
                                    </Col>
                                    // here
                                    {index%3===0 && </Row>}
                                )
                            })
                        }
```

But I get `Unexpected token, expected ","`

Edit:

I need to close  after third element, and reopen it at fourth.

Examples given doesn't work unfortunately.

Must be a thing similar to

```js
return (
                                    <>
                                        {
                                            (index % 3 == 0) ?
                                                <Row>
                                                    <Col>
                                                        <p>{index}</p>
                                                        <FormComponent
                                                            key={index}
                                                            field={item}
                                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                                            currentItem={{}}
                                                        />
                                                    </Col>
                                                
                                                :
                                                <>
                                                <Col>
                                                    <p>{index}</p>
                                                    <FormComponent
                                                        key={index}
                                                        field={item}
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                        currentItem={{}}
                                                    />
                                                </Col>
                                                </Row>
                                                </>
                                        }
                                    </>
                                )
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the correct approach. You should wrap all the related components inside your tenary operator, so the correct approach would be

```
   {index % 3 === 0 && (
    <Row>
        <Col>
            <FormComponent
                key={index}
                field={item}
                onChange={handleChange}
                currentItem={{}}
            />
        </Col>
    </Row>
   )
   }
```

This is not e.g. like java scriptlets where you add a tag or html in general according to a variable's value - so you specify if a start tag and an end tag should be rendered at html page - so `{index%3===0 && </Row>}` is not correct.

Comment: Please, see my edit. It is not exatcly what I need...

Comment: ok let me check.

Comment: i'm not sure if this can be done the way you are trying or you should merge these 2 fields into an array and then iterate that array.

Answer (score 0):

also, you need to add fragments`<> //some code</>` to your code

```
{
  companyConfiguration.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        {index % 3 === 0 && (
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <FormComponent
                key={index}
                field={item}
                onChange={handleChange}
                currentItem={{}}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        )
        }
      </>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Please, see my edit. It is not exatcly what I need...

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```js
{
    companyConfiguration.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    index%3 === 0 ? <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <FormComponent
                                key={index}
                                field={item}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                currentItem={{}}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Row> : <Col>
                        <FormComponent
                            key={index}
                            field={item}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            currentItem={{}}
                        />
                    </Col>
                }
            </>
                )
                })
                }
```

Comment: Please, see my edit. It is not exatcly what I need...